# aside bar not going to the place I want

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to build a website and I wanted to make a sidebar to go to one side of the page for the "What I Do" Section on my "about" page of the website, but for some reason it seems like it is merging with the article tag and I can not seem to separate it. Any idea what I need to do to fix this? I am also having trouble styling the lists on my "contact" page. Help would be appreciated.

http://danielcollins.mweb.spinspire.com/

Edit:Here is my code

```css
body{
    font-family:exo;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.5;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    
     
    }

.container{
width:80%;
margin:auto;
overflow:hidden;

}

.button_1{
    height:38px;
    background:#32cd32;
    border:0;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.dark{
    padding:15px;
    background:black;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

header{
    background:black;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-top:30px;
    min-height:70px;
    border-bottom:#32cd32 3px solid;
}

header a{
    color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 16px;
    
}

ul{
    margin:0;
        padding:0;
        
}




header li{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding{
    float:left;
}

header #branding h1{
    margin:0;
}

header nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a{
    
    font-weight:bold;
}    

header a:hover{
    color:#cccccc;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#showcase{
    min-height:400px;
     background:url('../IMG/Website1.jpg') no-repeat 0 -175px;
     text-align:center;
     color:white;
}

#showcase h1{
    margin-top: 90px;
    font-size:55px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#showcase p{
font-size:20px;
}

#newsletter{
    padding:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background:black;
    
}

#newsletter h1{
float:left;

}

#newsletter form{
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"]{
    padding:4px;
    height:25px;
    width:250px;
}

#boxes{
    margin-top:20px;
}

#boxes .box{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}

#boxes .box img{
    width:200px;
}



aside #sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    margin-top:10px;
}
    
aside #sidebar  .quote input, aside#sidebar .quote textarea{
 width:90px;
 padding:5px;
}



    article#main-col{
    float:left;
    width:65%;
    }    

    ul #contact li{
        list-style:none;
        padding:20px;
        border:#cccccc solid 1px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        background:#e6e6e6;
    }
        
    
    
    
    
footer{
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
}



@media(max-width: 768px){
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar{
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
  }

  header{
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }

  #showcase h1{
    margin-top:40px;
  }

  #newsletter button, .quote button{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }

  #newsletter form input[type="email"], .quote input, .quote textarea{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="Afforable and professional web design">
        <meta name="keywords" content="web design, affordable web design">
        <meta name="author" content="Daniel Collins">
        <title>Web Design | About</title>
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/newCascadeStyleSheet.css">
        
 </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="branding">
                    <h1><span class="highlight">Daniel's</span> Web Design Resume</h1>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href ="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="current"><a href ="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
       
        
        <section id="newsletter">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Subscribe to our Newsletter</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                    <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscribe</button>
                     </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <section id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <article id="main-col">
                <h1 class="page-title">About Me</h1>
                <p>
                   In turpis purus, suscipit sed lectus
                   lacinia, blandit tristique neque. Suspendisse 
                   tincidunt et tortor eu lobortis. Suspendisse potenti.
                   Proin lobortis porta nisl, semper pretium dui accumsan vel.
                   Aenean ultrices lectus id lacus sollicitudin, at consequat 
                   lorem lacinia. Fusce lacinia hendrerit augue, quis vehicula arcu
                   rutrum vel. Phasellus eget tempus odio.
                </p>
                <p class="dark">
                  In turpis purus, suscipit sed lectus
                   lacinia, blandit tristique neque. Suspendisse 
                   tincidunt et tortor eu lobortis. Suspendisse potenti.
                   Proin lobortis porta nisl, semper pretium dui accumsan vel.  
                </p>
            </article>
            
            
           <aside id="sidebar">
               <div>
                <h3>What I Do</h3>
                <p>In turpis purus, suscipit sed lectus
                   lacinia, blandit tristique neque. Suspendisse 
                   tincidunt et tortor eu lobortis. Suspendisse potenti.
                   Proin lobortis porta nisl, semper pretium dui accumsan vel. 
                </p>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Daniel Web Design, Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
     
      
  </html>
```

Comment: You've floated article to the left and it has width, so add float rigth and width to the side bar and it will they will be side by side.

Comment: Could you also provide us with some code you've tried so far? Maybe that will help solve your question.

Comment: and if you are wonder why is that it is because article and aside are block level elements.

Comment: If you look in my code you will see that I floated the sidebar to the right

Comment: your selector is not good. aside #sidebar should be ether aside#sidebar or aside or #sidebar

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, I remove aside from selector.

```css
body{
    font-family:exo;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.5;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    
     
    }

.container{
width:80%;
margin:auto;
overflow:hidden;

}

.button_1{
    height:38px;
    background:#32cd32;
    border:0;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.dark{
    padding:15px;
    background:black;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

header{
    background:black;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-top:30px;
    min-height:70px;
    border-bottom:#32cd32 3px solid;
}

header a{
    color:#ffffff;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 16px;
    
}

ul{
    margin:0;
        padding:0;
        
}




header li{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding{
    float:left;
}

header #branding h1{
    margin:0;
}

header nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a{
    
    font-weight:bold;
}    

header a:hover{
    color:#cccccc;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#showcase{
    min-height:400px;
     background:url('../IMG/Website1.jpg') no-repeat 0 -175px;
     text-align:center;
     color:white;
}

#showcase h1{
    margin-top: 90px;
    font-size:55px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#showcase p{
font-size:20px;
}

#newsletter{
    padding:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background:black;
    
}

#newsletter h1{
float:left;

}

#newsletter form{
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
}

#newsletter input[type="email"]{
    padding:4px;
    height:25px;
    width:250px;
}

#boxes{
    margin-top:20px;
}

#boxes .box{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}

#boxes .box img{
    width:200px;
}



#sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    margin-top:10px;
}
    
aside #sidebar  .quote input, aside#sidebar .quote textarea{
 width:90px;
 padding:5px;
}



    article#main-col{
    float:left;
    width:65%;
    }    

    ul #contact li{
        list-style:none;
        padding:20px;
        border:#cccccc solid 1px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        background:#e6e6e6;
    }
        
    
    
    
    
footer{
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
}



@media(max-width: 768px){
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar{
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
  }

  header{
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }

  #showcase h1{
    margin-top:40px;
  }

  #newsletter button, .quote button{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }

  #newsletter form input[type="email"], .quote input, .quote textarea{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="branding">
                    <h1><span class="highlight">Daniel's</span> Web Design Resume</h1>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href ="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="current"><a href ="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
       
        
        <section id="newsletter">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Subscribe to our Newsletter</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                    <button type="submit" class="button_1">Subscribe</button>
                     </form>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <section id="main">
        <div class="container">
            <article id="main-col">
                <h1 class="page-title">About Me</h1>
                <p>
                   In turpis purus, suscipit sed lectus
                   lacinia, blandit tristique neque. Suspendisse 
                   tincidunt et tortor eu lobortis. Suspendisse potenti.
                   Proin lobortis porta nisl, semper pretium dui accumsan vel.
                   Aenean ultrices lectus id lacus sollicitudin, at consequat 
                   lorem lacinia. Fusce lacinia hendrerit augue, quis vehicula arcu
                   rutrum vel. Phasellus eget tempus odio.
                </p>
                <p class="dark">
                  In turpis purus, suscipit sed lectus
                   lacinia, blandit tristique neque. Suspendisse 
                   tincidunt et tortor eu lobortis. Suspendisse potenti.
                   Proin lobortis porta nisl, semper pretium dui accumsan vel.  
                </p>
            </article>
            
            
           <aside id="sidebar">
               <div>
                <h3>What I Do</h3>
                <p>In turpis purus, suscipit sed lectus
                   lacinia, blandit tristique neque. Suspendisse 
                   tincidunt et tortor eu lobortis. Suspendisse potenti.
                   Proin lobortis porta nisl, semper pretium dui accumsan vel. 
                </p>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Daniel Web Design, Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
        </footer>
```